# Odd exception when calling a method in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx11

I am following the "3D game programming with directx 11" book (Frank Luna) and I am trying to render a cube. In the code there is this `m_device->CreateBuffer()` function which is giving me problems.

The exception I get is:

> Device was 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>
> DirectX11 exception in a method which is external to where the CreateDevice() method is called

So I tried to put it in the method where the device is created, and it gives no exception, so I'm wondering if I have to make the `m_device` something like global or I don't know.

```
struct Vertex {
        XMFLOAT3 Pos; XMFLOAT4 Color;
    }; 

 Vertex vertices[] = {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::White)},
        {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f),  XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Black)},
        {XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f),  XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Red)},
        {XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),  XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Green)},
        {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f),  XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Blue)},
        {XMFLOAT3 (-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Yellow)},
        {XMFLOAT3 (+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Cyan)},
        {XMFLOAT3 (+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4((const float*)&Colors::Magenta)}
    };
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    m_device->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mBoxVB); //exception is here
```

I repeat the code perfectly works in the method where I called the `CreateDevice()` method, but doesn't here, in another method of another class.

Comment: Enable the debug layer when you create your device. It will cause diagnostics output to be printed to the output window, which will be useful in narrowing down what you're doing wrong.

Comment: "device was 0xFFFFFFF..." sounds very much like you've corrupted memory someplace. I'd examine the value of "m_device" in the debugger and make sure it's the same pointer returned from your CreateDevice call.

Comment: Josh Petrie♦ hi, how can i examine the value of m_device in the debugger? Do i have to enable it or something

Comment: Josh Petrie♦ i mean how can i enable it? Meanwhile i'm searching on the internet

Comment: Please post your device creation code.

Comment: `UINT createDeviceFlags = 0; `

`#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)`
 `createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG; `
`#endif`

`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;`

 `hr = D3D11CreateDevice(0, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 0, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, 6, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &m_device, &featureLevel, &m_deviceContext);`

Comment: You say that this code doesn't work because it's "In another method of another class". Is this the same m_device that you created in your other class? Did you pass it to this class?

Comment: By "examine the value in the debugger" I simply mean put a breakpoint on the m_device->CreateBuffer line, run the program, and let the debugger stop them. Then put m_device in the watch window. If this doesn't make sense to you, you should probably read up on using Visual Studio's debugger (or the debugger of whatever IDE you are using) because it will be _extremely_ useful to you in the future.

Comment: Honeybunch yes i did, the class i'm using this code inside is a child of the class where the m_device is initialized and created

Comment: Josh Petrie♦ yeah i know how to use breakpoints, i'll try and i'll let you know

Comment: Josh Petrie♦ ok i used the watch window and a breakpoint on that line and it says "you can only use a pointer to an associated function only to call the function" (i translated it to english from italian becouse i've been trying to switch language of vs lots of time, without succes)

Comment: That's sounds like you are trying to put "m_device->CreateWindow" into the watch window. You just want m_device in the watch window.

Comment: Josh Petrie♦  so i used the quick watch (shift + f9) becouse i can't find watch window on visual studio 2015, i don't know, it should be in debug, windows, watch1 but is not there

Comment: m_device 0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd {...} type: ID3D11Device *
This is what i get if i quick watch only m_device (doesn't seem like an error, while the other did)

Comment: Yeah i checked and the address of m_device is the same ( 0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd) it gives read acces violation exception

Comment: What error checking do you have on your ``CreateDevice`` call? It seems likely you have a failed create device. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) and [Book Recommendations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/).

Comment: Solved the error by passing the device i created in the other class to the main, than from the main to the method where it wasn't working. At the end i did m_device=newDevice (the device i passed to th method where i had problem) so i have no issues i believe. Now i have another error in the D3DCompileFromFile function (of course), so i have to solve this, i think i can do it alone if a can't, i'll ask here, thanks for your help i solved it just becouse of you

Answer (score 1):

m_Device will be of type ID3D11Device*, i.e. it should be a pointer to a Direct3D 11 device object. In almost all Direct3D 11 applications, there is exactly *one* device, which is initialized with [D3D11CreateDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082(v=vs.85).aspx) or a similar function at the start of your program, and uninitialized at the end of it.

All of your 3D objects will usually be created by that device using functions like CreateBuffer. So a lot of times, a global pointer to the device makes sense. In standard notation, the "m_" prefix means that the variable is a *member* of the class. So if you've created the device in one class, but want to use it in another, the m_device pointer will need to be copied across.

It looks in this case like you've created the device, but either not stored its pointer, or you're using a different device pointer that hasn't been initialized. Perhaps in the constructor of the class that has the problem you can put something like:

```
ThisClass::ThisClass(ID3D11Device *dev): m_device(dev)
{
}
```

As long as the class instance is initialized after the device was created, and you have the device pointer from D3D11CreateDevice, you can pass it in to the constructor, and the m_device pointer will be correct.

Comment: I'd suggest that if you copy the device you should also AddRef it, then Release it in the destructor. Doing this means that your copy will be valid even if the original is Released.